# Conditional in for_each in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the next code that I have to execute when a variable's value equals to "X", for example:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "region" {
  for_each = aws_eks_node_group.managed_workers 

  autoscaling_group_name = each.value.resources[0].autoscaling_groups[0].name

  tag {
    key   = "topology.kubernetes.io/region"
    value = "eu-west-2"

    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

So I have to execute this code when a variable defined in my tfvars = "X". How I can combine the for_each and the conditional?

Comment: You would likely need to `merge` the exported resource attribute `object` with your variable `map`. We need to see the variable declaration to assist further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If entire resource is conditional, then you can do:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "region" {

  for_each = var.myvar == "X" ? aws_eks_node_group.managed_workers : {}

  autoscaling_group_name = each.value.resources[0].autoscaling_groups[0].name

  tag {
    key   = "topology.kubernetes.io/region"
    value = "eu-west-2"

    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. It's strange, the code is OK, but whatever it is the value of myvar the code doesn't executing..

Comment: @hachecheche Sorry, I don't know. Sadly, you haven't provide any examples or explanations what ` my tfvars = "X"` is. Thus its difficult to speculate. You can make new question if you want with new details and errors.

Comment: It is working @Marcin , the problem was double quotes in the conditional. If I remove it, it works!

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. I did my version of the for_each as `for_each = module.acm_expiring_certs_label.enabled == "true" ? data.aws_acm_certificate.acm_arn : {}`

Comment: @MertAlnuaimi No problem. Glad it worked out.